# CPU simulation in C

Tags: c, operating-system

I am working on a class project. I need to design a cpu, a lts(long term scheduler) and a dispatcher. Cpu and lts are threads, and they manipulate same thread-safe linked list(which means all operations on linked list must be mutually exclusive).Cpu has three components.(Boot: it will work only once at the beginning of the execution and get the first item from ready queue. Fetch: it will get the [IP]th instruction from code segment of the running process to IR. And execute it will execute the instruction in IR). Lts puts a hypothetical process in ready queue when its creation time is.Creation time is the number of total executed instructions before process is created.

```
DWORD WINAPI cpuFunction(){
    boot();

    while(cpu.runningProcess != NULL){
        WaitForSingleObject(readyQueue->mutex, INFINITE);
        fetch();
        exec();
        ReleaseMutex(readyQueue->mutex);

    }


    return (DWORD) 0;
}


DWORD WINAPI ltsFunction(){
    processList =createProcessList(FILE_NAME); 
    readyQueue = createList();
    while(1){
        WaitForSingleObject(readyQueue->mutex, INFINITE);
        if(processList != NULL){
            nextProcess = getFromList(processList,0);
            if(nextProcess->processCreationTime == cpu.executedInstructionCount){
                nextProcess = removeFromList(processList,0);
                addToList(readyQueue, nextProcess);
                printf("Process %d is in the ready queue.\n",nextProcess->processID);
            } else{
                nextProcess = NULL;
            }
        }
        ReleaseMutex(readyQueue->mutex);
    }
    Sleep(500);

}
```

In my code what i want to do is after every execution step, mutex in cpu function must be unlocked and lts should check if it is creation time of next process or not.That s why i am using mutexes. But the problem is they dont work. At first lts puts first process in ready queue(its creation time is 0), then cpu starts to run but it does not stop untill first process is terminated. However second process must be put in readyqueue after an insturuction is executed. I dont know how i fix and i really need help.

Comment: Does the lecturer have a Swastika? Or just want to put out of employment those that work for Intel of AMD?` Or is this homework that you have expanded to mean more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one thread needs to wait for other thread without having a mutex locked, the standard approach is to use to use conditionals. And if I read your question correctly, you have two threads which need to use something protected by same mutex, interleaved.

Important thing about conditionals is, they're always linked with a mutex. A thread locks a mutex, then starts wait on a conditional while mutex is locked, which frees the mutex. Then when the thread wakes from the conditional wait, it will again have the mutex locked. When another threads wants to wake up a thread waiting on a conditional, it must first lock the same mutex, then signal the conditional to wake up threads waiting it, then release the mutex (so the woken up thread can actually get the mutex lock).

This MSDN page provides an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But you'd do well to at least skim through everything under this MSDN topic about synchronization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I'm guessing what happens is that the first CPU "grabs" the Mutex before the second one has a chance to run. You could try this by adding a `sleep(20);` after the realease [this is obviously a poor solution, but it will show if this is really the problem].

Even if you have multiple cores/CPU's in your system, it's not guaranteeing that the longest waiting thread wins the race to grab the mutex.

Not using mutexes is of course a solution of sorts, but I think you still need to understand what you're doing wrong before you just say "Oh, mutexes don't work, I'll do something else" - because chances are that you will have the same or a similar problem somewhere else sooner or later, unless you understand what is going on.